# MagicalRecord maximum size?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, magicalrecord

I want to save only 20 last entities, and I want to remove other on start up.
 How can I do it??

Comment: Why don`t you manage your array or dictionary according to your need.

Comment: if it`s okay to you then you have to manage you data container(array or dictionary) in your viewcontroller.

Comment: no, I want remove element only then app terminate

Comment: and show 20 last element on start up

Comment: Add your logic in AppDelegate: `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` or `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` Every time user close your app delete others. If you wants to do the same but when user opens the app do it in: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`